# C Error 3 error C2065: 'num1' : undeclared identifier

Tags: c

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>


int main(){
    char letter;
    printf("Choose your calculation operation:7n/tA:Addition/n/tB:Subtraction/n/tC:Multiplacation/n/tD:Division/n/t");
    scanf("%c/n",letter);
    float num1, num2;
    printf("Enter a Num:");
    scanf("%f/n",&num1);
    printf("Enter the second Num:");
    scanf("%f/n",&num2);
     if(letter=='A' || letter=='a') printf("%f + % f = %f",num1,num2,(num1+num2));
     else if(letter=='B'||letter=='b') printf("%f - % f = %f",num1,num2,(num1-num2));
     else if(letter=='C'||letter=='c') printf("%f * % f = %f",num1,num2,(num1*num2));
     else if(letter=='B'||letter=='b') printf("%f / % f = %f",num1,num2,(num1/num2));
     else printf("You choosed wrong mark.");

}
```

Comment: What is your question? This code compiles perfectly.

Comment: sorry i can write man question thats why i am new ;

Comment: num1 and others are showed undecleried identifier???

Comment: I don't get undefined on any of the variables:

I see two problems. The first call to scanf that passes a char by value instead of a pointer to the char where you want the output

The last if statement that has a copy-paste error since you need D there instead of B again

and the slashes are all wrong way around

finally: http://www.giannistsakiris.com/index.php/2008/02/07/scanf-and-why-you-should-avoid-using-it/

Comment: i checked the problems you said but the same erros are stil given by compiler.

Answer (score 3):

In C89, variable declarations should be in the beginning of a block. The limit has been removed in C99.

According to your error code, you are using Visual Studio, which doesn't support C99 yet.

So, you should put declarations in the beginning of the function block.

```
int main(){
    char letter;
    float num1, num2;
    printf("Choose your calculation operation:7n/tA:Addition/n/tB:Subtraction/n/tC:Multiplacation/n/tD:Division/n/t");
```

One more thing, by `/n` and `/t`, you probably mean `\n` and `\t`.

Comment: you right actualy i repaired the problems /n and /t to \n and \t but i forget the save.after repairing same errors stil occurs.

Answer (score 1):

`letter` is of type `char` which means reading into `letter` using `scanf` should be passing by address i.e `scanf("%c", &letter);`